# unity 2 object spawn on button click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a grenade throwing script but when i test it, it always spawn 2 grenade at the same time.

```
public class GrenadeThrow : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject bulletprefab;
    float speed =20f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
        {
            Camera cam = Camera.main;
            GameObject Grenade = Instantiate(bulletprefab, cam.transform.position + cam.transform.forward, cam.transform.rotation);
            Grenade.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(cam.transform.forward * speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Input.GetButtonDown` is more appropriate for this than `Input.GetButtonUp`. You can try it and see if `Input.GetButtonDown` is still what you want.

> when i test it, it always spawn 2 grenade at the same time

Assuming that this is the actual code you are using to spawn and throw Objects, then it should work fine.

There two likely problems:

**1**.The `GrenadeThrow` script is likely attached to **the-same** GameObject multiple times.

[image]

**2**.The problem is likely to be that you have your `GrenadeThrow` script attached to **multiple** GameObjects. It should only be attached to one GameObject.

[image]

Comment: yeah i got it
i thrown the script into the character and then accidentally throw another gameobject with the script into the character again

Comment: Nice. Figured a duplicate is the problem. Happy coding!